# numba jit: failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject

Tags: numpy, numba, jit

I try to speed up the following function that saves the index position of the different labels present in a (large) 3 dimensional `np.ndarray` using jit.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def find_position(x, values):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            for k in range(x.shape[2]):
                values[x[i,j,k]].append((i,j))
    return values

labels = [1,2,3]
values = {l: [] for l in labels}
x = np.random.choice(labels,1000).reshape((10,10,10))

v = find_position(x, values)
```

However, I end up with the following error message:

```
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "find_position" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at <stdin> (3)
```

Does anyone has any tips how to get around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numba cannot operate on CPython objects like lists and dicts. They are called reflected lists. This is because Numba needs to define statically the type of the objets (and they must be homogeneous) so to generate a fast native code, while CPython objects are dynamically typed and lists/dicts data structures can contain heterogeneous objects. This is also what makes CPython data structure slow compared to Numba. The two approaches are incompatible. However, CPython can deal with typed data structure at the expense of additional overheads. Numba can only operate on typed data structure that can be created from non-typed (ie. reflected) ones. The creation of such data structure is pretty slow. In the end, it may not worth it.

You can create and fill a typed dictionary like this:

```py
import numba as nb

TupleType = nb.types.UniTuple(nb.int64, 2)
ValueType = nb.types.ListType(TupleType)
values = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(nb.int64, ValueType)
for l in labels:
    values[l] = nb.typed.typedlist.List.empty_list(TupleType)
```

Since `values` is typed, you can then pass it to Numba.

Note that dictionary are generally slow (whatever the language) as pointed out by @Rafnus. Thus, it is better to use arrays if you can, especially if the labels are small integers: you can build an array of `labelMax+1` items where `labelMax` is the biggest label value. This assume that the label IDs are positive one. If the number of label is very small (eg. <4) and known at compile time, then the method of @Rafnus may be faster.

Comment: great, I was looking for a way to tell numba the types and this works great! Unfortunately, Rafnus solution doesn't fit my actual problem as I made the example a lot easier to give a reproducible example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When using numba, there are a couple of things that are important to know:

- `Append()` is very slow! `append()` uses a lot of memory. It is much better to create an empty numpy array, and then slowly fill it with values.
- Try to use numpy functions when working with numba, as numba generally has very good support for them.
- **Avoid dictionairies!** Numba technically has limited support for them since update 0.52 [[see the documentation here]](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#dict) but they are not required to solve your problem, and for most problems there are often better (more performant) options available.
- **Do not use @jit, use @njit instead!** `@jit` calls numba in object mode, which means it handles all values as Python objects and uses the Python C API to perform all operations on those objects. This basically means that a function decorated with `@jit` is not faster than normal python code. Only when you use `@njit` (short for no-python) will you see a performance increase.

Taking all this in mind, i rewrote your code to this:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def find_position(inpt):
    # the 400 here is chosen arbitrarily. In this example, the final arrays will have a 
    # length of somewhere around 310-350, so with 400 we can be certain that
    # the arrays will be large enough to hold all the values
    arr1 = np.zeros((400, 2))
    arr2 = np.zeros((400, 2))
    arr3 = np.zeros((400, 2))
    x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(inpt.shape[0]):
        for j in range(inpt.shape[1]):
            for k in range(inpt.shape[2]):
                val = inpt[i,j,k]
                if val == 1:
                    arr1[x] = [i, j]
                    x += 1
                elif val == 2:
                    arr2[y] = [i, j]
                    y += 1
                else:
                    arr3[z] = [i, j]
                    z += 1
    return arr1[:x], arr2[:y], arr3[:z]

labels = [1,2,3]
np.random.seed(4)
inpt = np.random.choice(labels,size = (10, 10, 10))
v = find_position(inpt)
```

Comment: This method assume that the labels are always `[1,2,3]` which is probably not the case but unspecified by the OP. The `400` constant is pretty ugly and dangerous (dependent of the input). I propose you to use `np.empty((inpt.size, 2))` which will allocate a big array but the array is not mapped in physical RAM on mainstream platform so it is not an issue (unless `inpt` is really really huge so the OS cannot allocate it in virtual memory). An alternative solution is to use a 2 pass approach: the first estimate the size and the second fill the arrays.

Comment: yes, sorry I tried to compress my actual problem in a reproducible example, but the actual case includes arrays which are cubes of size of order 1e4. Moreover, instead of 3 labels there are in most cases about 20.000 different ones and I don't know how often every one occurs, but could be up to ~50.000 position indices. That's why I need to speed up the initial python function... but thanks!